# How do you change the color of glyphicons in a dynamic AngularJS ng-class?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

So, right now, I have a function called lessThan(a,b) that takes in 2 numbers that determines whether or not "a" is less than "b" and this returns a boolean value (true/false). I currently have a form where I have added a glyphicon to it such that a check mark displays when true, and an X displays when false. How ever, I can't seem to figure out how to make the color change for these two separate case. It either is always one color, or no color at all. I'd like the true case to change the check mark green, and the X to be red. Here is the line of code I am trying to change right now.

```
    <i ng-class="{'glyphicon glyphicon-ok': lessThan(a,b),'glyphicon glyphicon-remove': !lessThan(a,b) }"> </i>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just set the color in plain css.

```
.glyphicon-ok {
    color: green;
}

.glyphicon-remove {
    color: red;
}
```